# wp_list_pages doesn't work in hierarchical custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, hierarchical, list, pages

I've been bashing my head against my desk all afternoon trying to figure this out. I've got a custom post type all set up, with hierarchical set to "true" and I can assign parents and see the relationship in the back end. Which is great.

Except I want to list the children (and siblings) of my special new post type. I found this code

```
<?php if($post->post_parent)
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
else
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
if ($children) { ?>
<ul>
    <?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

which works perfectly when I put it into a page template for pages. But it returns squat for the custom post template.
I thought "$post->post_parent)" might be the issue -- but it's not:

```
 <h1 class="page-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'Return to %s', 'your-theme' ), wp_specialchars( get_the_title($post->post_parent), 1 ) ) ?>" rev="attachment"><span class="meta-nav">&laquo; </span><?php echo get_the_title($post->post_parent) ?></a></h1>
```

(lifted from an attachment template) does give me a back link to the parent. -- so maybe it has something to do with wp_list_pages? Maybe it's something else? I'd appreciate any ideas.

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As name hints `wp_list_pages()` is intended for use with pages. As in "a page page". It uses `get_pages()` internally, which has `post_type` argument that defaults to `page`.

I am not sure at all this is supposed to work for non-pages, but you can try to pass your custom post type as that `post_type` argument.

Comment: Hi Rarst -- thanks for the help:   The codex does say that you can run list pages through custom post types -- i tried to copy and paste the bit in but it was scrambled -- link is http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_members_of_a_custom_post_type --- any idea how i could put them together?

Comment: I am not sure from your comment - is this something that you discovered after my answer or something you tried and it didn't help?

Comment: the function in the codex will spit out all the pages in a given post type (pretty much treating it like a category, i think) -- I'm so so with php but I can't see a way to use it to list children -- i was wondering if you might?   Alternatively -- is there a way to run list pages through get_pages (with the post_type changed) manually?

Comment: If it helps what I'm trying to do is this:  show a bunch of books in a grid.  Each book opens to a synopis, but I need to link an exerpt somehow.  So I'm trying to create a relationship between two posts, essentially.  If there's a smarter way to do it -- that would be awesome

Comment: If code from your question does what you want for pages just try adding `&post_type=` your custom post type.

Comment: sorry, what would that look like?  should i be trying to define it first (ala $args = array(...)  or somewhere in the $children lines?  and thanks so much, really!

Comment: Something like `wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&post_type=book")` Using array is just alternative form of writing down arguments, it doesn't change what they should be.

Comment: Huh, still comes up blank.  Oy.  Guess i'll keep digging.  Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: @Martin No need for crude language.

Comment: Sorry John. It's just something i've been trying to do for the last 12 hours.  I'm pretty excited.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do something very similar.  Here's what I've got so far, using a custom post type of "product":

```
$children = wp_list_pages("sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&post_type=productE&echo=0")
```

this generates the list; unfortunately the links are generated as 
`siteurl.com/parent-product/child-page`

which causes a 404.  Doing a view from the edit screen shows the desired url as
`siteurl.com/?product=child-page`

I'm using the [More Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-types/) plugin, so set the permalink base for the custom post type to `product`, using the advanced tab while editing the type.

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Another consideration when using wp_list_pages for custom post types is making sure you register the custom post type with the 'capability_type' => 'page' NOT 'post'.... eg:

```
    register_post_type( 'mycpt',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'MyCPTs' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'MyCPT' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,  
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'menu_position' => 20,  
        'hierarchical' => true,  
        'rewrite' => true,  
        'supports' => array('title','editor','page-attributes')

    )
);
flush_rewrite_rules();
```